# JQuery UI modal dialog: cannot call methods prior to initialization

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

I have the following:

```
$(function(){
    $('#dialog').dialog({ modal: true, buttons: { "Ok": function () { $('#dialog').dialog("close"); } } });
}
```

I've tried numerous different forms of syntax with no luck. If I use `$(this).dialog("close");` I get the JS error complaining of calling methods prior to init, however when I use `$('#dialog').dialog("close")` it *almost* works. The dialog box pops up in the top left corner, the button doesn't render properly  - just a text-less circle that *does* close when clicked - and only when I give the popup focus does the modal overlay appear.

In my ASP.NET MVC view:

```
@{
    if (Model.response)
    {
        <div id="dialog" title="@Model.responseDialog.title"><p>@Model.responseDialog.content</p></div>
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, your code works as expected for me.

[image: scren grab]

Here are a couple of things to try to resolve the issue.

**Check your css and javascript files**

You need the relevant js and css files, and not duplicate or different versions of jQuery.

You can test this by ensuring **all** your existing ones are removed and replacing them with the cdn versions:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

**The calling dialog function is after the references**

Make sure that your dialog function is after the above references.

Comment: I deleted all of my MVC references to the old jQuery 1.7.1 and in my shared layout view I have the references you've outlined (jQuery 1.10.2 and jQuery UI 1.9.1 I do however still have these included `@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")` and `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")`

Comment: I would try removing them too, just to see if you can isolate the problem. It could be a conflict with one of those too.

Comment: I thought so too. I removed them and referenced only the main `Site.css` to no avail.

Comment: The only other things that I would have checked are that you only have one div with the id="dialog" and also that you are definitely calling the close on the same div (from your question you are). It's not caching it, start stop the web server just incase. Failing that I'm pretty stumped.

Comment: I have quite a few `#dialog` divs but they are all on separate pages, as IDs should be. I'll try targeting one specific ID name - EDIT Bah no luck.

Comment: Sorry, I'm out of ideas. Hopefully someone else will be able to help. Good luck.

Comment: Aha! So I moved all of my script references to the head instead of at the bottom of the body tag and also referenced a newer version of JQ UI and now it works! - kind of, my dialog is now behind its overlay hah

Comment: @Lee Nice one, that had me puzzled. Good luck with the rest. :)